# Change Background color to pink when checked in CSS

Tags: css

If I click the checkbox the `background-color` won't change to pink, what am I doing wrong here? Everytime I click the checkbox nothing happens.

```css
.joe:checked~.sub {
  background-color: pink;
}

.sub {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  top: 70px;
  right: 395px;
  width: 185px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="hoon" class="joe">
<li><a href="#"><label for="hoon">Services</label></a></li>

<div class="sub"> <li><a href="#">Take aways</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Online Order</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Pick and Drop</a></li></div>
```

Comment: I think it must be done in JavaScript not CSS as my experience.

Comment: .joe:checked ~ li label {
    background: pink;
}

Comment: as far as your label for check box is not followed directly after input tag in your css rules you should use li as well

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, `li` can only be direct children of `ul/ol`

Answer (score 0):

*There is no `.sub` class defined in your above example. If that wasn't intentional, then the issue is with your CSS selector precedence level.*

Your CSS should've been:

```css
.sub{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: grey;
    top: 70px;
    right: 395px;
    width: 185px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.joe:checked ~ .sub{
    background-color: pink;
}
```

The difference in above css from your one is that, `.joe:checked ~ .sub` selector styles are written post `.sub` class styles. It helps CSS to override the older `.sub` class styles.

Details on CSS Precedence: [Precedence in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/precedence-css-order-css-matters/)

**Solved:**

[Codesandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/interesting-browser-3iqz0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)